# use `numpy.take` to randomly select 2d points

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

**Problem Setup:**

- `points` - 2D `numpy.array` of length `N`.
- `centroids` - 2D `numpy.array` that I get as an output from `K-Means` algorithm, of length `k` < `N`.
- as a centroid initialization routine for an `MLE` algorithm, I want to assign each point in `points` a random centroid from `centroids`.

**Required Output:**

- A `numpy.array`  of shape (N, 2), of randomly chosen 2D points from `centroids`

**My Efforts:**

1. I've tried using the `numpy.take` with the `numpy.random.choice` as shown in `Code 1`, but it doesn't return the desired output.

**Code 1:**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(1, 10, 10).reshape((5, 2))
idx = np.random.choice(5, 20)
np.take(a, idx)
```

```
Out: array([6, 2, 3, 3, 8, 2, 5, 2, 6, 3, 3, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 2, 6, 5])
```

From [numpy.take documentation page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) I've learned that it chooses items from flattened array, which is not what I need.

I'd appreciate any ideas on how to accomplish this task. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar to `@Quang Hoang`'s answer, but a bit more intuitive in my opinion, will be :

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 10, 10).reshape((5, 2))
n_sampled_points = 20
a[np.random.randint(0, a.shape[0], n_sampled_points)]
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

One way is sampling the indexes, and then use that to index the **first dimension** of `centroids`:

```
idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(centroids)), size=len(a))

out = centroids[idx]
```